# Do IIS server settings force down app\web site settings?

Tags: asp.net, powershell, iis

I have to check and set "maxURL request filter" setting in IIS server with Powershell. I'm using these code to check current state of these setting:

```
$(Get-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -filter "system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits" -name "maxUrl").Value
```

As I understand, these command checks how it's set in server, but it also can be set for each site\app. Will server setting force down all app and sites settings, which been set before? And how can I check these stuff for all sites and apps if not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IIS, configuration can be set at the server level, site level, and application level. When configuration is changed at the server level, it usually affects all sites and applications, but in specific cases, site- and application-level configurations may override server-level configurations.

If you want to check the settings of all websites and applications, you need to iterate through each site and application and check their configuration.

You can using the following PowerShell script:

```
# Get all sites on the server
$sites = Get-WebSite

foreach ($site in $sites) {
    Write-Host "Site: $($site.Name)"
    
    # Get the site's configuration
    $siteConfig = $site.PSPath + '/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits'

    # Check if the setting is overridden at the site level
    if (Test-Path $siteConfig) {
        $maxUrl = (Get-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath $siteConfig -Name "maxUrl").Value
        Write-Host "maxUrl setting at site level: $maxUrl"
    } else {
        # If not overridden, use the server level setting
        $maxUrl = (Get-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -Filter "system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits" -Name "maxUrl").Value
        Write-Host "maxUrl setting at server level: $maxUrl"
    }
    
    # Get all applications under the site
    $applications = Get-WebApplication -Site $site.Name

    foreach ($app in $applications) {
        Write-Host "  Application: $($app.Path)"
        
        # Get the application's configuration
        $appConfig = $app.PSPath + '/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits'

        # Check if the setting is overridden at the application level
        if (Test-Path $appConfig) {
            $maxUrl = (Get-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath $appConfig -Name "maxUrl").Value
            Write-Host "  maxUrl setting at application level: $maxUrl"
        } else {
            # If not overridden, use the server level setting
            Write-Host "  maxUrl setting at server level: $maxUrl"
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like solution. Thanks a lot. Only one question left: "but in specific cases, site- and application-level configurations may override server-level configurations." I tried to find some official MS info about how it works but without any success. Could you please help to figure out how it works exactly?

Comment: @user21072039 you might get some basic ideas from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/the-configuration-system-in-iis-7#hierarchy But my suggestion is to go through test cases like https://github.com/jexuswebserver/JexusManager/tree/master/Tests to fully understand the exactly examples.